# Find the coefficient by regex?

Tags: c#, asp.net, regex

I want **regular expression** to find the coefficient, powers and the constants in the equation that have the general form `ax^3+bx^2+cx+d=0` for example:

```
2x^3+4x^2-6x+1=0
```

I tried the `@"\^\d+"` for the powers and I have no idea about how to find the decimal numbers before x as a coefficients

I am using C#

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Regexp expressions should also be aware of *negative* coefficients:

```
var pattern = @"(-?\d+)x\^?(\d+)?";
var formula = "2x^3+4x^2-6x+1=0";

foreach(Match match in new Regex(pattern).Matches(formula)) {
  Console.WriteLine("Coefficent \"{0}\"\tPower \"{1}\"",
       match.Groups[1].Value, match.Groups[2].Value);
}
```

The output is:

```
Coefficent "2"  Power "3"
Coefficent "4"  Power "2"
Coefficent "-6" Power ""
```

Please note: You will have to refine the Regexp pattern, if you want to (a) accept white space characters in a formula or (b) non-integer coefficients.

Comment: How I can Find the constants such as +6

Comment: @WalaaShaheen A "+" can be ignored, because it will not change the numerical value. However, if you always want to capture the sign, you can use this regex: `@"([+-]?\d+)x\^?(\d+)?"`.

Comment: there is missunsderstand i mean that i need regex to find d in ax^3+bx^2+c^x +d =0 
for example 2x^3+4x^2-6x+1=0 then the output will be 1 or if the example was 2x^3+4x^2-6x=-1 the output will be  1 ....thank you

Comment: @WalaaShaheen You find the constant left from "=" with "([+-]\d+)=" and the constant right from "=" with "=([+-]\d+)".

Comment: @WalaaShaheen Update: The sign is optional for the constant on the right. I added a ? in the regex. I.e. you find the constant left from "=" with "([+-]?\d+)=" and the constant right from "=" with "=([+-]?\d+)".

Comment: @WalaaShaheen Does this answer your question?

Comment: u almost answer my question thank you but the last question is that what if  [link]  string formula = "9x^3+4x^2+10-6x^4+5x=0"; [link] @JimiLoe ... regards

Comment: The strategy is that you perform both pattern matches for constants. At least one of them should match. In case of your last example with "= const", only the second pattern will match.

Comment: i found that if the constant may between the variables the best regex is that  @"(([+=-]|\s).\d+)[+=-]" at the left

Answer (score 1):

You can use `@"(-?\d+)x\^?(\d+)?"`

Matching group 1 => coefficients

Matching group 2 => powers

See [DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/iD7zC9/3) for explanation and exploration.